# How to iterate using for each in jsp

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp

[image: What I am trying to create]

Above is what I am trying to create

Hi,

Above is what I am trying to create using spring boot. My question is how do I properly iterate through a forEach loop and pull out the necessary data needed in JSP?
I thought I was doing it correctly but, I keep on getting an error saying 
"Don't know how to iterate over supplied "items" in <forEach>"

Please see my code below for what I am currently doing.

Thanks for your help in advance!!!

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/showOrders.html")
    public String listOrders(Model model) {

        ArrayList<Order> orders = os.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("allOrders", orders);


        return "allOrders";
    }
```

Service class for "Orders"

```
package com.sales.services;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.sales.models.Order;
import com.sales.repositories.OrderRepository;
@Service
public class OrderService {

    @Autowired
    OrderRepository or;

    public ArrayList<Order> findAll() {
        return (ArrayList<Order>) or.findAll();

    }

}
```

Repository class for orders

```
package com.sales.repositories;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.sales.models.Customer;
import com.sales.models.Order;

@Repository
public interface OrderRepository extends CrudRepository<Order, Long> {



}
```

Order class

```
package com.sales.models;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

@Entity
@Table(name="ORDERS")
public class Order {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="OID")
    private Long oId;

    @Min(1)
    @Column(name="QTY")
    private int qty;

    @Column(name="ORDDATE")
    private String orderDate;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="cId")
    private Customer cust;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="pId")
    private Product prod;

    public Long getoId() {
        return oId;
    }

    public void setoId(Long oId) {
        this.oId = oId;
    }

    public int getQty() {
        return qty;
    }

    public void setQty(int qty) {
        this.qty = qty;
    }

    public Customer getCust() {
        return cust;
    }

    public void setCust(Customer cust) {
        this.cust = cust;
    }

    public Product getProd() {
        return prod;
    }

    public void setProd(Product prod) {
        this.prod = prod;
    }

    public String getOrderDate() {
        return orderDate;
    }

    public void setOrderDate(String orderDate) {
        this.orderDate = orderDate;
    }

}
```

Customer class

`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
package com.sales.models;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;

@Entity
@Table(name="CUSTOMERS")
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="CID")
    private Long cId;

    @Column(name="CNAME")
    @NotBlank
    private String cName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="cust")
    private List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<Order>();

    public Long getcId() {
        return cId;
    }

    public void setcId(Long cId) {
        this.cId = cId;
    }

    public String getcName() {
        return cName;
    }

    public void setcName(String cName) {
        this.cName = cName;
    }

    public List<Order> getOrders() {
        return orders;
    }

    public void setOrders(List<Order> orders) {
        this.orders = orders;
    }   
}

````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````




Product Class
````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
package com.sales.models;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;

@Entity
@Table(name="PRODUCTS")
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="PID")
    private Long pId;

    @Column(name="PDESC")
    @NotBlank
    private String pDesc;

    @Column(name="QTYINSTOCK")
    @Min(value=0)
    private int qtyInStock;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="prod")
    private List<Order> ordersForProduct = new ArrayList<Order>();

    public Long getpId() {
        return pId;
    }

    public void setpId(Long pId) {
        this.pId = pId;
    }

    public String getpDesc() {
        return pDesc;
    }

    public void setpDesc(String pDesc) {
        this.pDesc = pDesc;
    }

    public int getQtyInStock() {
        return qtyInStock;
    }

    public void setQtyInStock(int qtyInStock) {
        this.qtyInStock = qtyInStock;
    }

    public List<Order> getOrdersForProduct() {
        return ordersForProduct;
    }

    public void setOrdersForProduct(List<Order> ordersForProduct) {
        this.ordersForProduct = ordersForProduct;
    }

}

````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````




Jsp file where I am trying to pull all the data from
````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
   pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
   <head>
      <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
      <title>List of Orders</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>List of Orders</h1>
        <c:forEach items="${allOrders}" var="ords">
            <b>${ords.oId} </b>

      <table>
         <tr>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Order Date</th>
            <th>Customer ID</th>
            <th>Customer Name</th>
            <th>Product ID</th>
            <th>Description</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <c:forEach items="${ords}" var="order">
         <tr>
         <td>${order.qty}</td>

         <td>${order.orderDate}</td>

         <c:forEach items="${ords.cust}" var="order">

         <td>${order.cId}</td>
         <td>${order.cName}</td>

         <c:forEach items="${ords.prod}" var="order">
         <td>${order.pId}</td>
         <td>${order.pDesc}</td>

          </c:forEach>
         </c:forEach>
         </tr>
         </c:forEach>

         </tr>
      </table>
       </c:forEach>
   </body>
</html>
````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Comment: Should this `<c:forEach items="${order.prod}" var="order">` be `<c:forEach items="${ords.prod}" var="order">` like the others?

Comment: Good eye, fixed that there. Still getting the same error though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the solve for this question

``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>List of Customers</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>List of Customers</h1>

    <c:forEach items="${ordrs}" var="ords">

     <c:forEach items="${ords.orders}" var="order">

        <b>${order.oId} </b>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Order Date</th>
                <th>Customer ID</th>
                <th>Customer Name</th>
                <th>Product ID</th>
                <th>Description</th>
            </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>${order.qty}</td>
                    <td>${order.orderDate}</td>

                    <td>${ords.cId}</td>
                    <td>${ords.cName}</td>



                    <td>${order.prod.pId}</td>
                    <td>${order.prod.pDesc}</td>

                </tr>

        </table>
        </c:forEach>



    </c:forEach>


</body>
</html>
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````